# Is it essential to declare "mod" for modules in Rust?

Tags: rust, module

I have following directory structure:

```
├── myappl
│   ├── Cargo.lock
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main.rs
│   └── target
│       ├── CACHEDIR.TAG
│       └── debug
│           ├── build
│           ├── deps
...
...
...

└── myfns
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

In myfns/src/lib.rs, I only have:

```
pub fn afn(){
  println!("in myfns::afn");
}
```

In myappl directory, I give command:

```
Cargo add myfns --path ../myfns
```

In myappl/src/main.rs, I have:

```
use myfns::*; 
fn main(){
    afn(); 
}
```

Then I build and run myappl:

```
cargo run myappl
```

Above scheme works, despite there being no module declaration in myfns as given in [example here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/visibility.html).

Should I add `mod` keyword in myfns/src/lib.rs:

```
 pub mod myfns {
    pub fn afn(){
      println!("in myfns::afn");
    }
 }
```

What is the advantage of declaring modules by `mod` keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not having any mods here, so you don't need the `mod` keyword. The way your code is set up is that you have two crates, one `bin` crate and one `lib` crate. Those two crates can of course use each other without any `mod` keywords, because neither of them have a `mod`, the `afn` function is declared in the top level of your `lib` crate.

You need the `mod` keyword if you want to have the `afn` function in a separate file in **the same** crate as the `main`. Like so:

```
    └── myappl
        ├── Cargo.lock
        ├── Cargo.toml
        ├── src
        │   ├── main.rs
        |   └── myfns.rs
```

If `myfns.rs` contains:

```rust
pub fn afn(){
  println!("in myfns::afn");
}
```

Your main has to be:

```rust
mod myfns;
 
fn main(){
    myfns::afn();
}
```

or:

```rust
mod myfns;
use myfns::afn;
 
fn main(){
    afn();
}
```

Mods are for code structuring. Of course they aren't necessary, you can write everything in a single file. But if you want to organize your code in multiple files without creating many crates, mods are what you want.

Comment: Do I need to add `pub mod {    }` around `afn(){...}` in myfns.rs file? You have not done so.

Comment: No, mods are create by **either** declaring a `mod { }` section **or** by having it in a separate file. The code I show here is exactly the content of your files, no further boilerplate needed.

Comment: Ok. Also, is the statement `mod myfns;` essential if one also writes `use myfns::afn;` (as you have done) in main.rs? I have never written in many example codes that I have tried and they were working with just use statement.

Comment: @rnso You might want to read https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod.html, including chapter `10.5. File Hierarchy`.

Comment: @rnso Yes. The `use` statement only brings it into scope; without a `mod` statement the compiler will never even look at the `myfns.rs` file. `use` can only reference already existing items, like `Cargo.toml` dependencies or `mod`s.

Comment: Can myfns module defined in myfns.rs file (with mod declaration) (in same folder as main.rs) be  added to Cargo.toml file so that mod keyword be avoided in main.rs?

Comment: @rnso No. `mod` is how Rust works - `Cargo.toml` is for **external** dependencies.

Comment: Can I put  module code `mod myfns { pub fn afn() {println!("in afn")}}` in main.rs ?

Comment: @rnso Yes, that you can do. Again, please read the [relevant chapter in the rust-by-example book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod.html), it's all shown there.